# Way to get data in a Node environment

Tags: node.js

In a node  environment , is it a good practice to make direct calls to database like oracle /sql using orace driver or sql driver  ?

The other way could be to make a api call in node (like a rest api ) to get the data .

The reason I am looking for alternative is because I have tried node oracle driver . Any error from within the driver is breaking the node instance and the try catch block is not helping .

I am trying to understand what is the best practice when dealing with sql databases ? Are the applications being developed in node using both sql and no-sql data source .

Please help me understand . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you post the code, and the error you're getting?

Comment: You can go either way - there is no specific right or wrong way.  For many specific databases, there is a `node` wrapper than gives you node-like async APIs you can use to talk to the database.  You'd just have to search NPM for a node-wrapper for your particular database.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to call the drivers directly, yes.  If there is an issue that causes Node to crash completely, that's a bug in the driver.  You should be able to find out from NPM where you can file a bug for the oracle driver.